# Ollama for python is extremely slow

Tags: python, ollama

I'm using Ollama library https://github.com/ollama/ollama-python for Python to build a sample application to describe images captured by webcam.

```py
import time
import cv2
import ollama
from ollama import generate

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

success, frame = capture.read()

ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)

frame = buffer.tobytes()
                
start = time.time()

response = ollama.generate(
    model="llava",
    prompt="Describe the image",
    images=[frame],
    stream=False
)

end = time.time()

print(response['response'])

print(end - start)
```

The process delays up to 3 minutes for each frame for a laptop with the following specs:

INVESP00246
13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1365U   1.80 GHz
32,0 GB
64 bits, x64

How can I optimize a litle bit the process?

Comment: 1.80 GHz is a rather slow clock speed to expect anything more performant; if you don't have a discrete GPU the only way you might be able make this more performant given the hardware is to use a smaller model.

Comment: @esqew Thanks for your answer! What model do you suggest to describe images?

Comment: Sadly, the answer is to buy a faster computer. You're finding out first hand why AI is currently considered a bit of a power-consumption problem - it needs a LOT of compute for the larger models.